# MS Access 2007/2010 Compact & Repair not working

Tags: ms-access

I have a database that I use in VB.  As records update theres a lot of useless info in there because access doesn't reuse the same spots.  So that information has to be removed.  Before I would use compact & repair and access 2000 and it would correct this.  It would correctly adjust the file size and remove all the wasted space or whatever happens in Access.

Compact and repair feature in 2007 and 2010 does not fix the file size.. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open that database in 2010, and do this:

1. Click the External Data ribbon group
2. Click the Access item
3. Use the Browse button to locate the database from which you want to import the database
4. Be SURE to select the first option (i.e. the "Import tables, blah blah" option)
5. Click OK
6. In the Import Objects dialog, select the tables you want to import. Be sure to review the settings in the Options button to see if you need any of those (chances are you do not).
7. Click OK, and Access will import the selected objects to your new database

Now, close out the database and make a copy of it. Reopen the new database, and Compact it.

If you're still have troubles after that, then there is a good chance that you have troubles with the installation of Access/Office or Windows on your machine. Be sure that you've fully updated Office and Windows, and try again.

If you're still having troubles compacting, then you may need [read this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6875337-1cd0-459a-b1b0-4747e55bdb76/corrupt-msmmmobmdb-file?forum=Offtopic).

Answer (score 1):

Another forum suggested doing it whilst saved locally rather than on a network drive.

Also it is a known issue and Microsoft released this hot fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952699/

It's noted that whilst the write up doesn't mention the fix, applying it does actually solve the problem.